# How to calculate the volume of a tetrahedron?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals

Suppose that 
$$
I=\iiint_{V}f(x,y,z)dxdydz
$$ 
where $f(x,y,z)$ is a continuous function, $V$ is a tetrahedron whose vertices are $P(2,2,0), A(-2,0,0), B(0,0,2)$ and $C(1,1,3)$. I want to ask you how can we express the integral $I$ in the form like $\int_0^a dx\int_0^b dy \int_0^c dz f(x,y,z)$? if $f(x,y,z)=1$, then what's the volumn of the tetrahedron.  I don't know how to do it actually.

Comment: In your case maybe is better start doing a movement that leaves a face of tetrahedron lying in a coordinate plane.

Comment: @Martín-BlasPérezPinilla: Yar, good idea. But I don't really know how to handle it in practice. Can you provide me with more details?

Answer (score 0):

The volume of the tetrahedron as a function of the 12 coordinates of the 4 vertices is given
in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetrahedron . This is a standard application of variable substitution
of analysis:
A new coordinate system is introduced in which the edges $P\to A, P\to B$ and $P\to C$ are mapped
onto the unit axes into the directions $(0,0,1), (0,1,0), (0,0,1)$, and where $P$ is mapped
onto the origin. This is a linear transformation,
with a matrix in which the 9 coordinates of the 3 edge vectors in the old coordinate system
are the entries, so the Jacobian of the transformation is just the determinant of that matrix
with the 9 coordinates. Because that Jacobian does not depend on the new coordinate system (it's just a constant), the volume integral is the Jacobian times the volume in the new coordinate system. Finally, the volume of the simplex (standard tetrahedron) in that
coordinate system is the volume of $x\ge 0, y\ge 0, z\ge 0, x+y+z\le 1$, which is
$\int_0^1 dz \int_0^{1-z}dy \int_0^{1-y-z}dx=1/6$.